# Div to always occupy the size of the window in height and width

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to enter the page to display a div on the entire screen (full width and full height) whatever the size of the browser window. That is to say, that div occupies ALL and until you do not scroll you do not see what is underneath.

It seems to work in the high, because even if you make it higher or smaller the next div below is not seen unless you scroll down, so far so good.

But in the width is another matter, it does not cover me the totality, and on top if I reduce the width of the window of the navigator the text is not molded to that width and the horizontal scroll appears.

Translated with [www.DeepL.com/Translator](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator) (free version)

HTML code

```
<div id="slider-total">
        <h1>Prueba de titulo</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rem nesciunt et explicabo impedit ducimus facere quam ipsum vero, accusamus molestias! Dolore perferendis pariatur esse at eaque qui aspernatur consectetur laboriosam.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="siguiente">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iste blanditiis sint labore, veritatis quidem sed nemo iure velit tenetur aspernatur facere quasi ullam assumenda, recusandae cupiditate laborum dolore excepturi eveniet?</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cumque quis iure sunt temporibus nostrum voluptatum doloremque, explicabo deleniti voluptatibus a enim nobis, tenetur perspiciatis repellendus error unde libero vero voluptatem! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo asperiores ullam ratione iusto error minima temporibus dolores facere, aliquam alias dicta eveniet, debitis quo deserunt soluta, voluptatum optio suscipit expedita. Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Delectus enim esse porro mollitia, facilis dolor voluptate iste, facere maxime minus id suscipit. Quaerat dolorum suscipit quo maiores quas temporibus tempore. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia placeat ullam amet ipsa libero quibusdam inventore fugit dolorum nostrum, animi velit reprehenderit neque, doloribus repudiandae enim vitae ducimus qui harum? Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eaque dolorem sapiente a, ea fuga voluptate mollitia inventore, impedit nihil optio aut itaque consectetur! Corrupti reiciendis quis, odit ducimus quod obcaecati!</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iste blanditiis sint labore, veritatis quidem sed nemo iure velit tenetur aspernatur facere quasi ullam assumenda, recusandae cupiditate laborum dolore excepturi eveniet?</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cumque quis iure sunt temporibus nostrum voluptatum doloremque, explicabo deleniti voluptatibus a enim nobis, tenetur perspiciatis repellendus error unde libero vero voluptatem! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo asperiores ullam ratione iusto error minima temporibus dolores facere, aliquam alias dicta eveniet, debitis quo deserunt soluta, voluptatum optio suscipit expedita. Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Delectus enim esse porro mollitia, facilis dolor voluptate iste, facere maxime minus id suscipit. Quaerat dolorum suscipit quo maiores quas temporibus tempore. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia placeat ullam amet ipsa libero quibusdam inventore fugit dolorum nostrum, animi velit reprehenderit neque, doloribus repudiandae enim vitae ducimus qui harum? Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eaque dolorem sapiente a, ea fuga voluptate mollitia inventore, impedit nihil optio aut itaque consectetur! Corrupti reiciendis quis, odit ducimus quod obcaecati!</p>
    </div>
```

CSS code:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#slider-total {
    width: 100vh;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #444;
    color: white;

    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your width is `100vh`, or 100 percentiles of the viewport *height*. It makes sense, therefore, that the width of the `<div>` will be smaller than needed if you have a viewport that is wider than it is tall. It should be `100vw`, or 100 percentiles of the viewport *width*.